# Javascript AutoSuggest/Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have data set of 1000s of values which I need to provide an autosuggest/complete on. I currently have one that runs ajax, but I find it extremely slow.

The way it needs to work like Google's or Icon Finder's. But I don't want it to submit when a match ahs been found.

I will also need this to work similar to stackoverflow tags so only match parts.

Any suggestions?

Using this one currently:

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=ajax-dynamic-list

Comment: yes- jquery UI autocomplete w/ ajax. it's quite fast. if you say that you're using it and finding it slow- perhaps the problem is in the server code that serves that ajax request. have you tried profiling it? (using firebug, you can see how long a request takes). perhaps posting your server-side code might help

Comment: Example of what you have? Maybe we could tell you why it runs extremely slow...

Comment: I'm not currently using jquery's, i didin't know they had an inbuilt one.

Comment: It's not built into the core library, it's in jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ Definitely browse through all the examples on the right; there's very likely to be an example that suits your purpose well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejohn has posted several articles about dictionnary search (which is basically what you do when you do autocompletition).
You should take a look :

http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/

http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/